# How to change label color when input field receives text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I'm confused on why I get this error when I link my Javascript to multiple pages. I'm trying to use Javascript to change the color of a form label as soon as it's input field contains text. It works fine on the Log In section, but doesn't work and gives me an error when I link it to the SignUp.html file. Here's a link to my project on codepen, if you wan't an example of what I'm talking about. I'd really appreciate any help!

```js
// LOGIN INPUT VARIABLES
let usernameInput = document.querySelector("#usernameInput");
let passwordInput = document.querySelector("#passwordInput");
// SIGN UP INPUT VARIABLES
let firstNameInput = document.querySelector("#firstNameInput");
let lastNameInput = document.querySelector("#lastNameInput");

usernameInput.addEventListener("input", function() {
    document.querySelector("#usernameLabel").style.color = "#98589e";
    if (usernameInput.value == '') {
        document.querySelector("#usernameLabel").style.color = "#b9c0c8";
    }
});

passwordInput.addEventListener("input", function() {
    document.querySelector("#passwordLabel").style.color = "#98589e";
    if (passwordInput.value == '') {
        document.querySelector("#passwordLabel").style.color = "#b9c0c8";
    }
});

firstNameInput.addEventListener("input", function() {
    document.querySelector("#firstNameLabel").style.color = "#98589e";
    if (firstNameInput.value == '') {
        document.querySelector("#firstNameLabel").style.color = "#b9c0c8";
    }
});

lastNameInput.addEventListener("input", function() {
    document.querySelector("#lastNameLabel").style.color = "#98589e";
    if (lastNameInput.value == '') {
        document.querySelector("#lastNameLabel").style.color = "#b9c0c8";
    }
});
```

https://codepen.io/EricGFig/project/editor/ZgPgRe

Comment: Can you include the specific error message you get?

Comment: The error you're getting is that when you try to find the input tags, it returns null. You need to find out if it is a naming problem

Comment: @NocNit this is the error message -> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at scripts.js:8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you have is

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

It points to line 8. Indeed in your `signUp.html` file you have no element called `#usernameInput` (nor `#passwordInput` actually).

So `usernameInput` and `passwordInput` are both undefined when you load this file in `signUp.html` (they are defined only when loaded in `logIn.html`)

Therefore you shouldn't be using the same JavaScript file for the two pages.

You should only have the following JavaScript code for the `signUp.html` page:

```
let firstNameInput = document.querySelector("#firstNameInput");
let lastNameInput = document.querySelector("#lastNameInput");

firstNameInput.addEventListener("input", function() {
    document.querySelector("#firstNameLabel").style.color = "#98589e";
    if (firstNameInput.value == '') {
        document.querySelector("#firstNameLabel").style.color = "#b9c0c8";
    }
});

lastNameInput.addEventListener("input", function() {
    document.querySelector("#lastNameLabel").style.color = "#98589e";
    if (lastNameInput.value == '') {
        document.querySelector("#lastNameLabel").style.color = "#b9c0c8";
    }
});
```

If you really want to keep a single JavaScript file, consider using functions to separate your code. For instance, have a function for the login style handling and another one for the signup style handling.

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU x 100! I appreciate your help, I was trying to solve this for quite some time now. I'm learning javascript and pretty rusty right now, not to sure how I'd do this using functions like you mentioned, but making two files definitely helped. Once again, thank you very much!

Comment: No problem @EricGFig, don't worry, it will come with some practice. Consider accepting answer/upvoting for future reference. btw your project on codepen looks really nice!

Comment: haha thanks! and I tried upvoting your answer, but it says I don't have enough reputation, sorry! kinda new to stackoverflow too smh, just started coding recently.

Comment: Yes, I forgot you can't upvote yet, however, you can always accept answers ([see here on how](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/366767)). SO is a great place to learn to code and help others.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code fails is because your trying attach event listener on a non existing element (null).

In order to solve this either create two separate JS files or add if statement around your listeners:

```
// LOGIN INPUT VARIABLES
let usernameInput = document.querySelectorAll(".usernameInput");
let passwordInput = document.querySelectorAll(".passwordInput");
// SIGN UP INPUT VARIABLES
let firstNameInput = document.querySelectorAll(".firstNameInput");
let lastNameInput = document.querySelectorAll(".lastNameInput");

if (usernameInput) {
  usernameInput.addEventListener("input", function() {
    document.querySelector("#usernameLabel").style.color = "#98589e";
    if (usernameInput.value == '') {
        document.querySelector("#usernameLabel").style.color = "#b9c0c8";
    }
  });
}

if (passwordInput) {
  passwordInput.addEventListener("input", function() {
    document.querySelector("#passwordLabel").style.color = "#98589e";
    if (passwordInput.value == '') {
        document.querySelector("#passwordLabel").style.color = "#b9c0c8";
    }
  });
}

if (firstNameInput) {
  firstNameInput.addEventListener("input", function() {
    console.log('!!');
    document.querySelector("#firstNameLabel").style.color = "#98589e";
    if (firstNameInput.value == '') {
        document.querySelector("#firstNameLabel").style.color = "#b9c0c8";
    }
  });
}

if (lastNameInput) {
  lastNameInput.addEventListener("input", function() {
    document.querySelector("#lastNameLabel").style.color = "#98589e";
    if (lastNameInput.value == '') {
        document.querySelector("#lastNameLabel").style.color = "#b9c0c8";
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated by other answers, the code is failing because it's trying to find a DOM object that doesn't exist.

The way I would handle this though is with CSS classes. I would replace your JS with:

```
var trigger = document.getElementsByClassName('input-trigger')
for(var i = 0; i < trigger.length; i++) {
  trigger[i].addEventListener("input", addListener);
}

function addListener() {
    var labels = this.parentNode.childNodes;      
    for(var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        if (labels[i].className == 'input-validate') {
            if (this.value === '') {        
              labels[i].style.color = "#b9c0c8";
            } else {
              labels[i].style.color = "#98589e";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just need to add the class 'input-trigger' to the input(s) you want to trigger the color change and 'input-validate' to the labels you want to have their colors changed.

The code above is more concise. It's triggered by the first class, then looks at the parent element of the triggering element, then selects any labels with the 'input-validate' class inside that parent element.

Here's a snippet example of this:

```js
var trigger = document.getElementsByClassName('input-trigger')
for(var i = 0; i < trigger.length; i++) {
  trigger[i].addEventListener("input", addListener);
}


function addListener() {
  var labels = this.parentNode.childNodes;      
    for(var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
      if (labels[i].className == 'input-validate') {
       if (this.value === '') {       
          labels[i].style.color = "#b9c0c8";
        } else {
          labels[i].style.color = "#98589e";
        }
      }
    }
 }
```

```html
<ul class="form-list">
  <li class="form-list-row">
    <label id="usernameLabel" class='input-validate'>Username or Email</label><br>
    <input id="usernameInput" class='input-trigger' type="text" required>
  </li>
  <li class="form-list-row">
    <label id="passwordLabel" class='input-validate'>Password</label><br>
    <input id="passwordInput" class='input-trigger' type="password" required>
  </li>
</ul>
```

While any of the other examples given will work, I always prefer to try and write concise, reusable code.

Hope that helps!